# Diamond Inheritance Lowest Base Class Constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, diamond-problem

The Code is as follow :

#### The Code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Animal{
   int a;

    public:
    Animal(int a) : a(a){}
    int geta(){return a;}
};

class Bird : virtual public Animal{
    string b;
    public:
    Bird(int a , string b) : Animal(a) , b(b){}
};

class Fish : virtual public Animal{
    int f;
    public:
    Fish(int a , int f) : Animal(a) , f(f){}
};

class Unknown : public Bird, public Fish{
    char u;
    public:
    Unknown(int a , int f , string b , char u )
     : Bird(a , b) , Fish(a , f) , u(u){}  //Problem
};
```

#### **The Question :**

1.)How am I going to initialize all the superclass if the Unknown class is instantiated?Since there's only one instance of Animal will be created , how can I avoid mysef from having to call its constructor twice ?

Thank you

Comment: If you're encountering the diamond inheritance pattern in the real world, please rethink your design and see if it doesn't make more sense to use composition instead of inheritance. You should in general prefer composition to inheritance.

Comment: @RobK Nonsense. "Diamond", or shared base classes, are common in OOP.

Comment: @curiousguy I'm glad I don't work on the projects you work on if you're running into diamond pattern inheritance. In 20 years of professional development in C++, I have never once needed to use it.

Comment: @RobK What's the problem?

Comment: Because, as I said above, when the diamond pattern is encountered, it's usually because one is inheriting when one should be composing. It's reflective of a poor design which decreases maintainability. I won't say it's never the right thing, but I've never seen an instance where it was.

Comment: @RobK I came here encountering the same problem when building UI classes for a firmware: On the hardware I've got buttons, I've got LEDs, and I've got buttons with an associated LED. It seemed logical to me to have a common UIElement class, an UIButtonInput and UILEDOutput derived from it, and a UILEDButton inheriting from both so I can talk to it like to any other UIElement when e.g. updating hardware and controller state in the main loop. Is this a case for diamond inheritance or why should I better compose here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The most derived class initializes any virtual base classes.  In your class hierarchy, `Unknown` must construct the virtual `Animal` base class (e.g. by adding `Animal(a)` to its initialization list).

When constructing an `Unknown` object, neither `Fish` nor `Bird` will call the `Animal` constructor.  `Unknown` will call the constructor for the `Animal` virtual base.

Comment: if i call the constructor of Animal class in the Unknown , how about the Bird and Fish ? How am I going to initialize their value respectively

Comment: They will not call the `Animal` constructor:  only the most derived class (`Unknown`, in this case) gets to call the constructors of any virtual base classes.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis How members of class bird and fish are  going to set ?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Thanks for that simple yet insightful explanation! I wonder - why is that so? Does the virtual inheritance mechanism work this way because otherwise we would allow ambiguous values for grandparent class members (here: Animal) when we initialize the grandparent class with different members in the parent inheritance layer?